# Pandas groupby throws: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown in the picture:

[problem dataframe: attdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e5y4.png)

I would like to group the data by Source class and Destination class, count the number of rows in each group and sum up Attention values.

While trying to achieve that, I am unable to get past this type error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-6f2c8b3de8f2> in <module>()
----> 1 attdf.groupby(['Source Class', 'Destination Class']).count()

8 frames
pandas/_libs/properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in _factorize_array(values, na_sentinel, size_hint, na_value)
    458     table = hash_klass(size_hint or len(values))
    459     uniques, labels = table.factorize(values, na_sentinel=na_sentinel,
--> 460                                       na_value=na_value)
    461 
    462     labels = ensure_platform_int(labels)

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

```
attdf.groupby(['Source Class', 'Destination Class'])
```

gives me a `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f1e720f2080>` which I'm not sure how to use to get what I want.

Dataframe attdf can be imported from : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t_h4b8FQd9soVgYeiXQasY-EbnhfOEYi

Please advise.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) either provide the code to create a dataframe, or paste the data as text so users can copy them to reproduce your question

Comment: What is `print (attdf.info())` ?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 13264 entries, 0 to 13263
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Source               13264 non-null int64
Destination          13264 non-null int64
Attention            13264 non-null float32
Source Class         13264 non-null object
Destination Class    13264 non-null object
dtypes: float32(1), int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 466.4+ KB
None

Comment: included link to csv of the dataframe now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

attdf = pd.read_csv("attdf.csv")

print(attdf.groupby(['Source Class', 'Destination Class']).agg({"Attention": ['sum', 'count']}))
```

Output:

```
                                 Attention      
                                       sum count
Source Class Destination Class                  
0            0                  282.368908  1419
             1                    7.251101    32
             2                    3.361009    23
             3                   22.482438   161
             4                   14.020189    88
             5                   10.138409    75
             6                   11.377947    80
1            0                    6.172269    32
             1                  181.582437  1035
             2                    9.440956    62
             3                   12.007303    67
             4                    3.025752    20
             5                    4.491725    28
             6                    0.279559     2
2            0                    3.349921    23
             1                    8.521828    62
             2                  391.116034  2072
             3                    9.937170    53
             4                    0.412747     2
             5                    4.441985    30
             6                    0.220316     2
3            0                   33.156251   161
             1                   11.944373    67
             2                    9.176584    53
             3                  722.685180  3168
             4                   29.776050   137
             5                    8.827215    54
             6                    2.434347    16
4            0                   17.431855    88
             1                    4.195519    20
             2                    0.457089     2
             3                   20.401789   137
             4                  378.802604  1746
             5                    3.616083    19
             6                    1.095061     6
5            0                   13.525333    75
             1                    4.289306    28
             2                    6.424412    30
             3                   10.911705    54
             4                    3.896328    19
             5                  250.309764  1132
             6                    8.643153    46
6            0                   15.249959    80
             1                    0.150240     2
             2                    0.413639     2
             3                    3.108417    16
             4                    0.850280     6
             5                    8.655959    46
             6                  151.571505   686
```

Comment: are you doing any other manipulation on the df? I tried with you .csv file and I get correct results with no errors

Comment: actually no.. I'm also getting the right results on importing my own csv.. i don't understand what the problem was..

Answer (score 2):

@Adam.Er8 and @jezarael helped me with their inputs. The unhashable type error in my case was because of the datatypes of the columns in my dataframe.

[Original df and df imported from csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soqF0.png)

It turned out that the original dataframe had two object columns which i was trying to use up in the groupby. Hence the unhashable type error. But on importing the data into a new dataframe right out of a csv fixed the datatypes. Consequently, no type errors faced anymore.